# Yii add validation error to related model

Tags: php, yii

I have two models Session and SessionTicketType as below. I want to to display SessionTicketType error in Session model on validation.

model Session.php

```
public function relations() {
     $relations['sessionTicketTypes'] = [
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'SessionTicketType',
            'session_id',
            'index' => 'ticket_type_id'
        ];
        return $relations;
   }
```

And

model SessionTicketType.php

```
  public function relations() {     
       $relations['session'] = [self::BELONGS_TO, 'Session', 'session_id'];
       return $relations;
    }

    public function rules(){
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules[] = ['selected', 'safe'];
        $rules[] = ['slots', 'validateSlots'];
        return $rules;
    }    

    public function validateSlots($attribute,$params) {
            if($this->slots < $this->getQuantitySold()){
               $this->addError('slots', 'Slots can not be less than total booking.');
    }

    public function getQuantitySold()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT SUM(i.quantity)
            FROM booking b
            INNER JOIN booking_item i ON b.id = i.booking_id
            WHERE b.session_id = :session_id
            AND i.ticket_type_id = :ticket_type_id
            AND b.status IN (:status_completed)";

        return Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar([
            ':session_id'    => $this->session_id,
            ':ticket_type_id' => $this->ticket_type_id,
            ':status_completed' => BookingStatus::STATUS_CONFIRMED,
        ]);
    }
```

I have Session form in which multiple sessionTicketype added.
I want to add this error (validateSlots()) on session validation.
Validation code validateSlots() in sessionTicketType is not displaying any error on session update and save data.
How can i display error and restrict saving .
Or is there any other way where i can add this validation in session model

Comment: your validation will run when `SessionTicketType`'s `save` or `validate` is called, you can write similar kind on rule in `Session` model